# How to share major and minor version of the main application with its DLLs?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have a large WinForms application (C# , .NET 4.5.2) with several own DLLs (plug-ins for the application), all as different Projects in the same Solution. I use Visual Studio 2015 Community.

The main app and all the DLLs have their version number assigned in their respective AssemblyInfo.cs files like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Now I want to up the version of the application to, say, 2.0.*. I also want all the DLLs to be 2.0.*. The way I currently have it I would need to go into each DLL and manually change the version to 2.0.*.

Is there a way to inherit the "2.0" part from the application so that, in future, I would only have to change major and minor version number in one place?

I did some searching but was not able to find the answer.

**Update:**
What I was hoping is that I can replace

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

with something like:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion(some_string + ".*")]
```

where "some_string" is a string containing the major and minor version number. But I wouldn't know where I can define that string, or if this is possible at all.

Comment: Assembly version are supposed to change if something changes. It is not meant to have exact copy of the same library but with different version numbers. But aside that you can in Visual Studio execute a "pre-build" script (batch, exe..) and that script you cna write it yourself and make it edit the assembly.cs and then when it will compile the new value will be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a link to the original `AssemblyInfo.cs` file to the other project via the project solution explorer:

*Right click on the project* -> `Add` -> `Existing item` -> `Add as link` (from the dropdown menu)

Now, once you change the original `AssemblyInfo.cs`, any changes will be applied to all the projects to which the file was added as a link.

**Edit:**

To avoid duplicating attributes that should be unique per assembly (such as the GUID), make two files, one for the shared attributes like version number, and another for assembly specific attributes. No one forces you to put everything into the same file. It does not even have to be named `AssemblyInfo.cs`

Comment: You should add a warning that this will also make all DLL to share ALL the values including assembly and assembly guid. Not only the version number

Comment: OK, if I understand this correctly, this would use the same AssemblyInfo.cs for all projects that I add this link to? This would also mean that all the other properties in the AssemblyInfo.cs would be the same? I'm using different values for "AssemblyTitle", "AssemblyDescription" and so on for each DLL.

Comment: @yesyes What we do is have a shared linked `SharedAssemblyInfo.cs` that only contains the shared info like version numbers and company info. We then remove that info from AssemblyInfo.cs and our projects just use both files

Comment: Thanks. This sounds like what I need. However, I can't seem to find the "Add as Link" option. I can do "Add..." -> "Existing Item..." and then I get a select file dialogue. When I do that I get a *copy* of the file and I can edit both files independently. Does the "Add as Link" option not yet exist in VS 2015, maybe?

Comment: @yesyes You have to click on the small triangle arrow next to the Add button

Comment: ah, yes, I just found it ;-) Thanks!!

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted. I have changed the whole solution now and it works a treat! Thanks so much. Marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio of you can set Pre build events.

- Right click the project and select properties
- Go to Build Events

then in the first box for pre-build event you can launch a simple script like this

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release C:\AssemblyChanger.exe $(ProjectDir)
```

This sample script above will Launch "AssemblyChanger.exe" located on your c drive and it will pass the current Visual Studio project folder as an argument. from there it is very simple to read the Assembly.cs on the specific project that manage the "version" and edit the one in the path that was pass as argument. Plus this will only be called if you are in Release mode (that "if" can be removed without a problem).

You can create a simple console application to do that.

That script can be set in all DLL pre build event so when they compile they call the script and they will get their assembly edited before the compiler create the DLL.